# Focused label displays dotted line as border

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, border

I am sending focus to a WPF label programmatically. However, when I do this a dotted line appears around the label. I do not believe that this is the border brush, especially since I explicitly set it to be Transparent. Does anybody know how I can get rid of this dashed/dotted line?

If it helps, the dashes appear only on the left and right. And, the label is within a StackPanel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried clearing out its `FocusVisualStyle`?

```
<Label FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}">
    My Label
</Label>
```

Comment: Accepted yours as the answer because it has a full example, and I do not know who posted first

Answer (score 2):

See [FrameworkElement.FocusVisualStyle Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.focusvisualstyle.aspx). You can set it to `Null`.

Comment: +1, sorry not sure who got to it first and Kevin's answer had the full example, so I let that edge out yours

Comment: No problem. He was first too as you can see if you mouseover the answering time. ;)

Comment: 9 seconds - that's pretty close! Thanks for the mouseover tip...never realized that feature was there.